# Create click off event on animated navigation dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 problems:

1. I'm trying to create an click-off event, where a click off of the "nav" menu is detected, which triggers the deselection of the open list element and retracts its respective dropdown content.
2. My current code doesn't allow another list element/navigation item without dropdown content to be added, as doing so hinders the entirety of the code from working. I'd like to add another "nav" list element that doesn't have dropdown contents, without hindering the functionality of the other list elements and their respective dropdown content.

Here is my code (also available on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bm7qoe3k/4/)):

```js
$(function() {

  function animate() {
    $('#nav .nav-ul li').off('click', animate)
    var $detected = $(this).closest('.nav-ul');
    $detected.find('li.detected').removeClass('detected');
    $(this).addClass('detected');

    //figure out which rel to show
    var ulToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

    //hide current rel
    if ($('.substitute .sub-child.active').length > 0) {
      $('.substitute .sub-child.active').hide(700, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#' + ulToShow).fadeIn(528, function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $('#nav .nav-ul li').on('click', animate)

        });
      });
    } else {
      $('#' + ulToShow).fadeIn(528, function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#nav .nav-ul li').on('click', animate)
      });
    }
  }

  $('#nav .nav-ul li').on('click', animate);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  background-color: /*blue*/
  ;
  float: right;
}

#nav .nav-ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  background-color: /*yellow*/
  ;
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  border-right: solid 2px #000000;
}

#nav .nav-ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

#nav .nav-ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #E51D27;
}

#nav .nav-ul li.detected {
  color: #E51D27;
}

#nav .substitute {
  float: right;
  background-color: /*pink*/
  ;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child.active {
  display: block;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="" rel="pay1">Color</li>
    <li rel="pay2">Shape</li>
    <li rel="pay3">Size</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="substitute">
    <div id="pay1" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
        <li>Green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay2" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Square</li>
        <li>Circle</li>
        <li>Triangle</li>
        <li>Diamond</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay3" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Small</li>
        <li>Medium</li>
        <li>Large</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I'm trying to create an click-off event, where a click off of the "nav" menu is detected, which triggers the deselection of the open list element and retracts its respective dropdown content.

For this you could create a click event handler on the body that closes the menu if it's open. Something like this:

```
// close menu when clicking anywhere on the document
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $("#nav li.detected").removeClass("detected");
  $("#nav div.active").hide(700, function() { $(this).removeClass("active"); });
});
```

Then to avoid it from closing when you click on the menu, you can use [`.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in the `animate` function to stop the bubbling of the events up the DOM tree when clicking on it.

> 2. My current code doesn't allow another list element/navigation item without dropdown content to be added, as doing so hinders the entirety of the code from working. I'd like to add another "nav" list element that doesn't have dropdown contents, without hindering the functionality of the other list elements and their respective dropdown content.

This happens because you are associating and disassociating events every time that you click on the menu (something that is not really necessary), so when one of the navigation items doesn't have a dropdown associated to it, the event handler is removed (with the `off()` in the `animate` function) but it is not associated again, which causes this behavior that you don't want.

The solution is simple: there's no apparent need to be detaching and re-attaching the click event handlers every time that the `animate` function is called. Remove the call to `off` and `on` within the `animate` function and that would be it.

---

Here you can see both changes applied to your code:

```js
$(function() {

  function animate(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $detected = $(this).closest('.nav-ul');
    if (!$detected.hasClass("active-animation")) {
      $detected.addClass("active-animation");
      $detected.find('li.detected').removeClass('detected');
      $(this).addClass('detected');

      //figure out which rel to show
      var ulToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

      //hide current rel
      if ($('.substitute .sub-child.active').length > 0) {
        $('.substitute .sub-child.active').hide(700, function() {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          $('#' + ulToShow).fadeIn(528, function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $detected.removeClass("active-animation");
          });
        });
      } else {
        $('#' + ulToShow).fadeIn(528, function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $detected.removeClass("active-animation");
        });
      }
    }
  }

  $('#nav .nav-ul li').on('click', animate);

  // close menu when clicking anywhere on the page
  $(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#nav li.detected").removeClass("detected");
    $("#nav div.active").hide(700, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  background-color: /*blue*/
  ;
  float: right;
}

#nav .nav-ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  background-color: /*yellow*/
  ;
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  border-right: solid 2px #000000;
}

#nav .nav-ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

#nav .nav-ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #E51D27;
}

#nav .nav-ul li.detected {
  color: #E51D27;
}

#nav .substitute {
  float: right;
  background-color: /*pink*/
  ;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child.active {
  display: block;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav .substitute .sub-child ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="" rel="pay1">Color</li>
    <li rel="pay2">Shape</li>
    <li rel="pay3">Size</li>
    <li>No Dropdown</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="substitute">
    <div id="pay1" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
        <li>Green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay2" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Square</li>
        <li>Circle</li>
        <li>Triangle</li>
        <li>Diamond</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay3" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Small</li>
        <li>Medium</li>
        <li>Large</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nicely answered. This is the best answer - I withdraw mine. Very good explanations. +1

Comment: @gibberish Thanks, there was no need to withdraw yours though

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Thank you for your answer. Clarified a lot. I'm new at JQuery, as you can likely tell. You're a major help.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro My only problem is that, if I rapidly click off of an "li" element and onto another before the dropdown animation occurs, the correct "li" element will be highlighted, however, the wrong dropdown content will be displayed. I'd fixed that problem in the previous code, but I'm lost as to how I'd replicate the effect in this code.

Comment: @DanielJohnson that could be easily fixed by using a sentinel variable to prevent the click. Instead of disabling/enabling the click event handler, you can add/remove a class to the navigation. If the class is present, do not execute the body function. Basically, where you had the `off`, you would add the class; and where you had the `on`s, you would remove that class. I edited the code to fix that.